# Missing 'ELEMENT' when using switchTo().frame() in javascript

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium webdriver with javascript on Chrome and I'm trying to interact with an input inside an iframe like so:

```
      await driver.switchTo().frame(By.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/ng-form/div/ui-view/div/dqcomponent[3]/ng-form/div[1]/div[1]/iframe/html/body/form/input[1]'));
```

I am able to use `.click()` on the element just fine but the above line causes the following error:

```
(node:4514) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: InvalidArgumentError: invalid argument: missing 'ELEMENT'
```

I have tried switching to the element using CSS but it produces the same error, how can I properly switch to said iframe?

My webdriver version is `^4.0.0-beta.1` and my chrome driver is `^88.0.0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

await driver.switchTo().frame expects an element not locator

Use it like

```
  Elem = await driver.findElement(By.id("some if"))
  await driver.switchTo().frame(Elem)
```